# c++: accessing vector elements using a pointer to the start of it

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector, std

I have a vector of pointers to Machines:
That is,

```
vector<Machines*> m;
```

I populate the vector with pointers and I know the number of machines that exist.
If I created a pointer to a pointer of Machines to the start of the vector:

```
Machines** m2;
m2 = & m[0];
```

would I be accessing the vector members as I increment that '0'?

```
m2[0]->dostuff;
m2[1]->dostuff;
...
```

It seems doable to me but I'm not sure if that's allowed. :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's certainly legal, but seems a bit odd when you have a vector already there - side question: why a vector of pointers? Why not just a vector of Machines?

Comment: @John3136 probably Machine is a base class, in which case you need pointers to prevent slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's allowed, but do you realize you can do the following and there is no reason to use `Machines** m2;`?

```
vector<Machines*> m;
// Fill vector here
m[0]->dostuff(); // I assumed dostuff was a function
m[1]->dostuff();
```

Comment: Oh yes I know, I was simply wondering if the above would work. I am not coding that way by any means. Thanks a lot for your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

If reallocation of vector memory happens, the pointer in your code will be invalid.

It may happens when pushing elements to vector.

Answer (score 1):

Since `vector` is guaranteed to allocate continuous memory, this seems correct. But why would you? You have all this functionality directly in `vector`.